# SQL Server: batch with primary key violations not fully executed using ODBC SQLExecDirect

Tags: sql-server, odbc

In SQL Server by default, a primary key violation does not abort the batch. This behaviour can easily be reproduced using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), for instance:

```sql
create table dbo.A (id int primary key)

insert dbo.A values (0) --works!
insert dbo.A values (0) --primary key violation
insert dbo.A values (0) --primary key violation
insert dbo.A values (0) --primary key violation
insert dbo.A values (1) --works!

select * from dbo.A
```

Alas, when I run similar code from my C++ program using the ODBC function SQLExecDirect(), I get non-deterministic behaviour, i.e. the batch is aborted after "a couple of" primary key violations and the remainder is not executed.

Consider the following loop which adds an insert statement to the batch and executes it:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
   ssSql << L"insert dbo.A values(" << i << L")" << std::endl; // append 
   wcscpy_s(wszInput, ssSql.str().c_str());
   SQLExecDirect(hStmt, wszInput, SQL_NTS);
}
```

Every iteration will add one more primary key violation to the batch, but the expectation is that the final insert statement will eventually be executed.

When using "ODBC Driver XX for SQL Server", where XX is 11, 13 or 17, I only get values 0-24 inserted, no more. If I copy the batch from the 99th iteration and run it in SSMS, I get the remaining values (25-99) inserted.

When using the old, Windows bundled "SQL Server" driver, sometimes I get all values inserted, sometimes less. Hence, I don't see any deterministic behaviour in this.

Is this a bug/limitation of ODBC, the driver or SQL Server?

Comment: Check `XACT_ABORT` is it on or off? `(@OPTIONS & 16384)=16384` if 0 then off otherwise on. Best practice is to have it **on** and not send bad keys to the DB, do separate checking

Comment: @Charlieface: It's off (by default) and I want it that way in order to insert whichever don't exist AND to get the primary key violations reported to the client.

Comment: As I said, are you **sure** `XACT_ABORT` is off? And why are you not checking the return result from `SQLExecDirect`?

Comment: The error code says nothing about how many inserts worked and when/if the batch was aborted which should actually have never been the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug/limitation of ODBC, the driver or SQL Server?

The Driver.  All drivers simplify the Client/Server interaction to make programming easier, but every simplification creates corner cases.

That batch will return a variety of messages to the client, including rowcount notifications and error messages, and complicating things, SQL Server will buffer the messages on the server for performance reasons.

So what's probably happening is that the driver aborts the batch when it sees the first error message, which it's perfectly free to do.   But when it *sees* the first error message is not the same as when the first error message is *sent*, because of the server-side message buffering.

Best practice is to always use XACT_ABORT ON, and if you want to send a bunch of rows to SQL Server and insert whichever don't exist, you can craft INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS queries, use TSQL's MERGE or set IGNORE_DUP_KEY on the index.

Comment: I'm aware of MERGE and the like in order to prevent primary key violations. But the idea was both to insert whichever don't exist AND to log at client side that primary key violoations did happen. SSMS and sqlcmd work as expected -- obviously they don't use ODBC, but OLEDB!?

Comment: You could just insert one row per statement, or wrap each INSERT in TRY/CATCH.

Comment: Big question: why does Microsoft's ODBC driver show this behaviour? It looks like a flaw, if not even a bug to me. Especially as SSMS and sqlcmd behave as expected.

Comment: @MarkusNißl See [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html) also for why best practice is to keep `XACT_ABORT ON`, and do error checking via T-SQL. You can just `SELECT` back to the client all failing rows, it's not a big deal.

Comment: As to whether it's a flaw or bug, perhaps.  But the fact that the old SQL Server driver shows this behavior, it would probably be a breaking change.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In my tests, the old driver was also non-deterministic in that it succeeded to insert 98 instead of 100 rows. Though this is four times more than what the newer drivers achieve. IMHO the breaking change is that the ODBC drivers are non-deterministic from the very beginning.

Comment: @Charlieface I appreciate you pointing out workarounds and best practices. I also know Erland Sommerskog great articles on TSQL error handling. But my original post was about why the ODBC driver does not behave as described by Erland and Microsoft.